# Como mostrar uma imagem cujo caminho está no banco de dados?

Tags: php, imagem, extjs-4

Estou usando ExtJS 4 e PHP.

Tenho uma imagem salva numa pasta do servidor e o seu caminho está salvo no meu banco de dados. Tentei fazer algo assim:

### Código no controller:

```php
onVerImgClick: function(btn, o, e0pts){
    var grid = btn.up('grid');
    var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    var produtoId = records[0].data.id;
    //var image = Ext.create('ExtMVC.view.verImagem');
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'php/importadorDadosImagem.php',
        success: function(response){
            var array = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            var cont = 0;
            var caminho;
            while(cont < array.data.length){
                if(produtoId == array.data[cont].idProduto){
                    caminho = array.data[cont].imagem;
                }
                cont++;
            }
            cont = 0;
            if(caminho != null){
                var image = Ext.create('ExtMVC.view.verImagem');
                image.getEl().set({
                    src: caminho
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### verImagem.js

```php
Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.verImagem', {
   extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
   alias: 'widget.verimagem',
   autoShow: true,
   modal: true,
   width: 400,
   height: 400,
   items: [
       {
           xtype: 'component',
           autoEl: {
               tag: 'img',
               src: ' '
           }
       }
   ]
});
```

### importadorDadosImagem.php

```php
<?php
include("connect.php");

$queryString = "SELECT idProduto, imagem FROM imagens";

//consulta sql
$query = mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());

//faz um looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
$dados = array();
while($dado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $dados[] = $dado;
}

$total = count($queryString);

echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => mysql_errno() == 0,
    "total" => $total,
    "data" => $dados
));
```

Desse jeito, nenhum erro é mostrado. Porém, a imagem não aparece.

Answer (score 1):

bom dia, você já tentou primeiramente se conectar ao banco de dados pelo PHP? você tem que ter no banco de dados a seguinte informação, nome e extensão da imagem, então no php você poe em uma variável, o endereço completo da pasta raiz até a pasta onde a imagem está, então concatena com o nome e extensão da imagem, ai basta inserir em uma variável javascript e atribuir no seu código para exibir a imagem.

exemplo

SQL = nome | ext = imagem.ext

PHP = servidor/pasta/subpasta/imagem.ext

EJS = http://servidor/pasta/subpasta/imagem.ext

Comment: No banco de dados eu tenho salvo o caminho completo da imagem. Por exemplo: ./uploads/Jellyfish.jpg
Então, após escolher o registro que quero ver a imagem, eu recupero o caminho através de uma requisição Ajax e tento setar o src.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto cuidado com este trecho ./ em experiencia própria, vi que isso sempre da erro, no lugar de isso, utilize um request de url completa, e veja se só isso já fará a imagem aparecer, ponha manualmente em uma variável com http e tudo e veja se funciona, se sim, basta criar um request da sua url completa

Comment: Se eu colocar o caminho completo não dá. Se eu colocar ./uploads/Jellyfish.jpg no src do script verImagem.js, deixando-o estático, a imagem aparece.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto então se você poe estático ele aparece com esta formatação, já se busca do banco de dados ele não aparece, então seu erro não está no js e sim no banco de dados, como você está buscando no banco de dados?

Comment: Adicionei o código PHP onde importo os dados da imagem.

Comment: Eu tenho todos os produtos em um grid. Para adicionar uma imagem, eu seleciono o produto e clico num botão. Para ver a imagem, é da mesma forma. No BD, Eu tenho uma tabela para os produtos e outra tabela para as imagens. Então para referenciar uma imagem, eu pego o id do produto selecionado. Na hora de recuperar, eu comparo o id da imagem com o id do produto, se for igual e pego o caminho e tento setar no src. Mas não tá setando.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto experimente utilizar PDO você verá que é muito mais simples e mais seguro, segue um exemplo.

mas, vi que você não adicionou um critério de busca no seu querystring

Comment: Você verificou se o retorno do php está chegando para o ajax? Pois pelo que vi você não definiu o header no php, coloque isto antes do echo: 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: `<?php try { $a = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . "; dbname=" . $base, $user, $pass);
$a -> setAttribute(PDO :: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO :: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$a -> exec("set names utf8");
$b = $a -> prepare("SELECT idProduto, imagem FROM imagens WHERE idProduto = :var");
$b -> execute(array(":var" => $var));
$c = $b -> fetchAll();
if(count($c)) {
foreach($c as $d) {
echo $d["imagem"]; } }
$a = null; } catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e -> getMessage(); } ?>`

Comment: Não poste código nos comentários, edite sua resposta e de a sugestão lá.

Comment: @fly flourigh o retorno tá correto sim. Botei para mostrar no console e tá saindo direitinho. O header tá definido no connect.php.

Comment: Sugiro que debug em partes então, defina um string estático para o src invés da variável caminho, se passar vá mudando de nível até chegar onde falha.

Comment: pois é, terá que ver em cada parte onde está o erro, pois pelo que entendi, a variavel de um que é o caminho, não está passando para a variavel de outro para exibir a imagem, ou seja, voce busca com php e insere o caminho em uma variável, este caminho então passa para outra variavel do javascrip e então é exibido, bom, no caso, voce abre um produto, este produto tem um id este id tem várias imagens estas imagens exibem em vários lugares, ou seja, ao requisitar o produto ele cria um array com todas as imagens, caso voce crie um loop, ele exibe as imagens antes de passar para o javascript?

Comment: Consegui carregar as imagens como eu queria. Criei uma outra variável e a fiz receber o componente que tem o xtype = 'image'. A partir daí, consegui fazer o novaVariavel.setSrc(caminho); 
O problema agora é a forma como eu salvo o caminho das pastas que o @flyflourigh falou. Eu estou mandando o caminho ./uploads/ ele não salva e mostra o seguinte erro: Warning:  move_uploaded_file(./uploads/Koala.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\app\extjs-crud-mvc\php\recebeUpload.php on line 56.

Comment: Se eu colocar ../uploads/ ele salva, mas na hora de ver a imagem ele da um not found, ou seja, não encontra a pasta com a imagem.

Comment: para isso, basta você criar duas variáveis, uma para inserir a imagem no banco de dados que seria a ./uploads/ e uma outra para mover a imagem que é a ../uploads/

Comment: basicamente você irá concatenar um ponto . antes do outro ponto .. na hora de mover apenas

Comment: Pronto! Funcionou. Obrigado, galera!